# TS transpiling: babel vs tsc

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I am setting up a TS project for my first time. And I'm curious - I can use and config Babel or just do `tsc ..` for transpiling.

What is the main difference between the two?

Comment: Babel transpiles es6 to es5 or es3. TSC transpiles Typescript to es6, es5 or es3

Comment: But for example, it is possible to transpile Typescript to es5 with Babel

Comment: No, but I suspect that `tsc` uses babel under the hood.

Comment: @Kokodoko it doesn't

Comment: How do you know? Anyway, I have never manually added Babel to my typescript projects. It's just not needed.

Answer (score 10):

Main difference is the support for the TypeScript language itself.

You can use `tsc` to transpile ES6+ to older versions of the standard, just as you would do with Babel, by basically putting `"strict": false` in your `tsconfig.json`. Or you can use a type checker like [Flow](https://flow.org/) on top of Babel to achieve similar effect to what the TypeScript compiler gives you by default.

AFAIK, `tsc` doesn't use Babel - I've seen them produce differently behaving code out of the same source .js file.

Comment: Could you point to the example or source where TSC and Babel produce different behaving code? that would be very interesting to analyse!

Comment: Here's a sample [code](https://gist.github.com/MayaLekova/3b0eb851baf7e6d6d6e863e5e3562f1d) that produces observable difference. 

This one is a little bit tricky, because popular browsers don't agree on the correct behaviour. TS follows one of the behaviours, while Babel does it the other way round.